# What does "defaults" contain?

Tags: parsing, ecmascript-5, abstract-syntax-tree, spidermonkey

I'm working with the **[Esprima](http://esprima.org)** parser, it outputs an [AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) format which is compatible with the [Mozilla Spider Monkey Parser API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey/Parser_API).

In the **[Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey/Parser_API#Functions)**, it specifies the `Function` node as:

```
interface Function <: Node {
    id: Identifier | null;
    params: [ Pattern ];
    defaults: [ Expression ];
    rest: Identifier | null;
    body: BlockStatement | Expression;
    generator: boolean;
    expression: boolean;
}
```

**What will the `defaults` property contain?** It always appears as just an empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

defaults of Mozilla JS AST contains ES6 default parameter values.

For example,

```
    function t(i = 20) { }

defaults will be [{ type: 'Literal', value: 20 }].
```

Because it is based on ES6 draft, Esprima master branch doesn't recognize it.